# Is oracle connection pool in C# based on application or operating system?

Tags: c#, oracle, oracleclient

The application is in C# and it is using Oracle connection with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll provided by Oracle. By default, it will get connection from connection pool every time.

I guess this ManagedDataAccess.dll is working together with Oracle client to manage the connection pool. Is oracle connection pool based on application or operating system? For example, we have two different independent C# applications, do they share the same applicatoin pool if their connection string are the same?

Comment: My understanding is the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` is the fully independent database provider implementation, that is it does not depend on an installed Oracle Client home as `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` does.

Comment: As to if the pool is shared across process, with quick dig through Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll with ILSpy I did not see anything that looks like it involved cross process coordination, so I would be surprised if the pool was shared.
however there is a lot of stuff going on in that dll,

Comment: Hi @AndrewMoskevitz, Many thanks.  For `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`, is it a new technology from oracle, to replace `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`?

Comment: `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` is a fully Managed (written in .net) database provider. If the computer has network access to the database server, it can connect without any additional installs.
`Oracle.DataAccess.Client` is a Managed Wrapper around the native OCI interface and requires an installed oracle client.
`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` does not strictly speaking *replace* `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` as it does not have all the functionality of the latter. however the missing functionality is less frequently used things like AdvancedQueueing and User Defined Types.

Comment: At this point i believe it is recommended to use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` and only use `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` if you need the extra functionality or if you support an existing codebase.